# Angular 14 form not binding data in dynamic form

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-dynamic-forms

I am trying to create a dynamic form to add actors to games in my angular website, but when I load in the page I get the following errors:

[image]

[image]

The second error happens on all input fields for the dynamic form part.

```
export class GameAddComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private gameService: GameService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: '',
      description: '',
      price: '',
      category: '',
      image: '',
      releaseDate: '',
      actors: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.formBuilder.control({
          name: '',
          isMale: '',
          birthDay: '',
        })
      ]),
    });
  }

  get actors() {
    return this.form.get('actors') as FormArray;
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    const values: Partial<Game> = {
      ...this.form.value,
    };
    console.log(this.form.value);
    this.gameService.addGame(values).subscribe();
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/games');
  }

  addField() {
    this.actors.push(this.formBuilder.control);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

```
<div class="container px-5 my-5">
  <form id="contactForm" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    
    <!--normal working input here-->

    <!--below is the dynamic form-->
    <i class="nav-icon bi bi-plus-circle-fill px-5" (click)="addField()"></i>

    <div *ngFor="let actor of actors.controls">
      <h2>Acteur</h2>
      <div class="form-floating mb-1">
        <div class="form-floating py-2">
          <input
            class="form-control"
            id="naam"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Naam"
            formControlName="name"
          />
          <label class="form-labels" for="name">Naam</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-floating py-2">
          <select
            class="form-select"
            aria-label="Default select example"
            formControlName="isMale"
          >
            <option value="0">Vrouw</option>
            <option value="1">Man</option>
          </select>
          <label class="form-labels" for="name">Geslacht</label>
        </div>

        <div class="pb-3">
          <label for="birthDay" class="px-2">GeboorteDatum:</label>
          <input type="date" id="birthDay" formControlName="birthDay" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-grid">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="submitButton" type="submit">
        Aanmaken
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

When I submit the form, the data from the dynamic part is not saved, so I'd guess it's because it can't find the properties in the formbuilder

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the following tutorial and got my application working,
https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/nested-formarray-example-add-form-fields-dynamically/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You created a single control here, which holds an object with 3 properties

```
this.formBuilder.control({
          name: '',
          isMale: '',
          birthDay: '',
        })
```

But your template tries to access those properties as formcontrols

```
<input
            class="form-control"
            id="naam"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Naam"
            formControlName="name"
          />
<select
            class="form-select"
            aria-label="Default select example"
            formControlName="isMale"
          >
<div class="pb-3">
          <label for="birthDay" class="px-2">GeboorteDatum:</label>
          <input type="date" id="birthDay" formControlName="birthDay" />
        </div>
```

**--> I believe you actually want another FormGroup here**

```
this.formBuilder.group({
          name: '',
          isMale: '',
          birthDay: '',
        })
```

Comment: How would I access this from the HTML, I have tried changing it to `formGroupName="actors"` or `formGroupName="name"` but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: `actor` (without s) is your FormGroup. `<div *ngFor="let actor of actors.controls" [formGroup]="actor">`

Comment: I get the following error when trying to add [formGroup].
Type 'AbstractControl<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'FormGroup<any>': controls, registerControl, addControl, removeControl, and 2 more